# Python epydoc how to hide subpackage

Tags: python, python-2.7, epydoc

I have a python package I am trying to document and I want to hide a sub-package that is being imported.

structure:

```
restapi #__init__.py
--> rest_utils
--> arc_restapi
--> open_restapi
   --> shapefile #__init__.py  # this is a new folder/package that I want to hide
```

The shapefile folder is in the directory where the restapi's `__init__.py` and other .py files reside.  How can I exclude this using [epydoc](http://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/~rgm/dazle/software/dics/src/epydoc-3.0alpha2/doc/using.html)s via the command line?

So far I have done this:

```
epydoc.py --html restapi restapi.rest_utils restapi.arc_restapi restapi.open_restapi -o C:\Users\calebma\Desktop\test --name="restapi" --url http://gis.bolton-menk.com/restapi-documentation/restapi-module.html
```

I can get this to work when I use the epydoc GUI and I reference the exact same files, but when I do it from the cmd it is adding documentation for `shapefile`, which is just a dependency module.  I think it is including shapefile because it is imported from the open_restapi.py file